# Newbie to LyX having issues with tex2lyx -f

Tags: lyx

I am working on an article with LyX, using the springer open template: http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex

Anytime I try to import I get the error:

```
An error occurred while running: tex2lyx -f"bmc_article.tex""bmc_article.lyx"
```

Any help?
Raheem

Comment: What is your OS? How did you install LyX? What version of LyX are you using? LyX has several Springer templates. Do they meet your needs? (see File > New From Template)

Comment: I am using Windows 8, I downloaded and installed LyX version 2.0.7 from LyX website. MikeTex 2.9 was also part of the installation. I am interested in the  "BioMed Central's TeX template" and it is not in "New From Template Folder"

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems like your question was already answered on the lyx-user list. If you want further help, follow the instructions and if you still get errors, reply to the lyx-users email with your progress and what you have tried (i.e. copying one of the existing layouts)

Comment: Read through Chapter 5, still no clue. Finally located the article.layout file, renamed it to bmcart.layout as directed, changed the first line and it refuses to save with an "Access Denied" error.

Comment: I suggest you respond to the email on lyx-users.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Heck answered this question on the lyx-users mailing list in [this thread](http://marc.info/?l=lyx-users&m=139645346023316&w=2):

> I think you get this error if you do not have a layout file for whatever  class the template uses. In this case, the class is `bmcart.layout`, and  unless you wrote a layout file yourself, you do not have one.
>
> Please see *Chapter 5* of the *Customization* manual for information on what  layout files are and so forth, if that did not make sense to you. Since *bmcart* is just a variant of article, you should at least be able to get  basic functionality by
>
> (i) copying the `article.layout` file into your LyX user directory;
>
> (ii) renaming it as `bmcart.layout`;
>
> (iii) changing the  first line to read:
>
> `\DeclareLaTeXClass{Article (BMC)}`
>
> (iv) reconfiguring LyX and then attempting to re-import.
>
> Probably a lot  of the template will import as ERT, since this layout file says nothing  about whatever is different about *bmcart*.